# Smooth border growth transition when inserting HTML causes it to grow?

Tags: css

I'm using JQuery to add html in a bordered div. Consequently the div grows in height. It abruptly changes size and I can't manage to smooth the transition. I've tried adding:

```
transition: border 0.5s ease;
```

But it doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: Transitions only work with numerical values. `auto` values won't be affected.

Comment: try `transition: all 0.5s ease;` since it's the height that changes, not the border

Comment: JQuery will add content instantly, There is no transition taking place as such....and you can't transtion an auto `height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your div to grow in size when you add html to it, try doing something like this:

```
    var container = $(".yourContainer");
    var htmlToAdd = $(".yourHtmlToAdd");

    htmlToAdd.appendTo(container).hide().slideDown(500);
```

the `hide().slideDown(500)` will cause your added html to grow in size causing your container div to grow in size as well.